# Tensorflow evaluation,

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

Given tensor names of the layers, is it possible to evaluate an input only for specific layers and in general is it possible to save all the results during the forward pass ?

Will be grateful for any help

Answer (score 1):

Question is a little unclear, but i think this is what you are after:

Each tensor or operation you create has a possible argument `name`. By providing a name for each tensor you can use [`tf.Graph().get_tensor_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_tensor_by_name) and pass you desired input in the `feed_dict` when calling that.

As for saving the results, you can save the current state of your model using the [tf.train.Saver()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Saver) class.

Here is a simple example of a model where in one script a model is created and saved, and then a second script this same model is loaded, and its Tensors accessed using [`tf.Graph().get_tensor_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_tensor_by_name).

**save_model.py**

```
#create model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3,3], name="x")
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[3,3], mean=0, stddev=0.5), name="w")    
xw = tf.multiply(x,w, name="xw")

# create saver
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# run and save model
x_input = np.ones((3,3))*2 # numpy array of 2s
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    xw_out = sess.run(xw, feed_dict={x: x_input})

    # save model including variables to ./tmp
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model saved with w at: \n {}".format(w.eval()))

>>>Model saved with w at: 
>>> [[ 0.07033788 -0.9353725   0.9999725 ]
>>> [-0.2922624  -1.143613   -1.0453095 ]
>>> [ 0.02661585  0.18821386  0.19582961]]

print(xw_out)

>>>[[ 0.14067577 -1.870745    1.999945  ]
>>>[-0.5845248  -2.287226   -2.090619  ]
>>>[ 0.05323171  0.3764277   0.39165923]]
```

**load_model.py**

```
# load saved model graph
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./tmp/model.ckpt.meta")

x_input = np.ones((3,3))*2 # numpy array of 2s
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore sesssion from saver
    saver.restore(sess, "./tmp/model.ckpt")
    print("Model restored.")

    # Check the values of the variables
    w = sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("w:0"))
    xw = sess.run(sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("xw:0"), feed_dict={"x:0": x_input})
    print("Output calculated with w loaded from ./tmp at: \n {}".format(w))

>>>INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./tmp/model.ckpt
>>>Model restored.
>>>Output calculated with w loaded from ./tmp at: 
>>> [[ 0.07033788 -0.9353725   0.9999725 ]
>>> [-0.2922624  -1.143613   -1.0453095 ]
>>> [ 0.02661585  0.18821386  0.19582961]]

print(xw)
>>>[[ 0.14067577 -1.870745    1.999945  ]
>>>[-0.5845248  -2.287226   -2.090619  ]
>>>[ 0.05323171  0.3764277   0.39165923]]
```

Note: the "`:0`" following the operation names in `get_tensor_by_name()` specifies that it is the *0th* tensor output by that operation that you want.

This code can be seen working in a set of jupyter notebooks [here](https://bitbucket.org/FinleyGibson/save-and-load-tf-model/src/master/), and there is another simpler implementation, for if you have the graph already constructed.